# Get "Speaking URL path segment" from english version

Tags: php, typo3, realurl

I am new to TYPO3. I have a webpage which is developed in TYPO3 with PHP.

In this they are creating page urls using **realurl extention**

My problem is I have a english and chinese version of a single page.

If "Speaking URL path segment" is empty in chinese version will it get from english version. Is it possible. I tried in google no answer. Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what your question exactly is but if you mean to show the English version of a page when the Chinese does not exist, maybe it's enough to set

```
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/TyposcriptConfiguration/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But its not works for me. When speaking url is empty, it takes the title from chines version as the URL instead of english(default lang) URL